# Update data with image with ajax in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to edit and update the data along with image with JQuery & AJAX in Bootstrap modal form in codeigniter Framework, but one of the input : file input is not required. 
if I input the data with no image file, it's always error.

here is the function :

```
function save(){
  $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
  $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable
  var url;

  if(save_method == 'add') {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('databerita/ajax_add')?>";
  } else {
    url = "<?php echo site_url('databerita/ajax_update')?>";
  }
```

ajax adding data to database

```
  var form = $('form')[0]; var formData = new FormData(form);
  formData.append("foto_berita", "file");
   $.ajax({
    url : url,
    type: "POST",
    data: formData,
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data)
    {

        if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
        {
            $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
            reload_table();
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++)
            {
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
            }
        }
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable


    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert('Error adding / update data');
        $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
        $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable

    }
});
}
```

the controller :

```
public function ajax_update()
{
    $this->_validate_update();

    $this->load->library('upload');
    $nmfile = "file_".time(); //nama file saya beri nama langsung dan diikuti fungsi time

    $config['upload_path'] = './assets/images/'; //path folder
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg|bmp'; //type yang dapat diakses bisa anda sesuaikan
    $config['max_size'] = '2048'; //maksimum besar file 2M
    $config['max_width']  = '1288'; //lebar maksimum 1288 px
    $config['max_height']  = '768'; //tinggi maksimu 768 px
    $config['file_name'] = $nmfile; //nama yang terupload nantinya

    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($_FILES['foto_berita']['name']){
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('foto_berita')){
            $berita = $this->upload->data();
            $data = array(
                'foto_berita' =>$berita['file_name'],
                'id_berita' =>$this->input->post('id_berita'),
                'isi_berita' =>$this->input->post('isi_berita'),
                'judul_berita' =>$this->input->post('judul_berita'),
            );      
            $this->m_databerita->update(array('id_berita' => $this->input->post('id_berita')), $data);
            echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE)); 
        }

    }else{
        $data_update = array(
            'id_berita' =>$this->input->post('id_berita'),
            'isi_berita' =>$this->input->post('isi_berita'),
            'judul_berita' =>$this->input->post('judul_berita'),
        );
        $this->m_databerita->update(array('id_berita' => $this->input->post('id_berita')), $data_update);
        echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
    }     
}
```

I have added the else function if the $_FILES is null, in non-ajax method it's working properly.

Thank you.

Comment: @raksdwija Remove `dataType: "JSON",` and add `async: false,`.

Comment: What error you got ?

Comment: here if(save_method == 'add') variable save_method gives what?

Comment: @ yash,thank you. I'll try.
@ gopal, I cant update data without submit image file, I want if I'm not submit image file.
the script execute 2 methods save data, 'add' and 'update'.

Comment: try to update your condition  `if(isset($_FILES['foto_berita'] ) && $_FILES['foto_berita']['name'])` and also check that column `foto_berita` is nullable.

Comment: instead of `echo` json plain..  do as `$this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode(array("status" => TRUE)));`